# Facebook PHP SDK v5 : How To Read Public Feeds of Page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm new to Facebook SDK.

I installed PHP SDK v5, but all the sample Codes (even in Facebook docs) i found so far are for SDK v4 .. to read the Public Feeds of a Public Page.

Let's say .. i want to read the most 5 recent "public" Posts by `/Google` page.

How do i read them in simplest and most recommended way for this, please?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the PHP SDK 5 is tagged with v4: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted#installation

Example code for the PHP SDK v5 can be found in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed#read

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{page-id}/feed'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

If you want to get the latest 5 entries, just use the limit parameter in your API call: `/{page-id}/feed?limit=5`